# Create an Array of Arrays with each Array indexed

Tags: scala

I would like to add Arrays together into an Array of Arrays. I would also like each Array to be indexed.

Input:

```
a = Array("a", "b", "c")
b = Array("d", "e", "f")
c = Array("g", "h", "k")
```

I want output like this:

```
a+b+c=> Array(("1",Array("a", "b", "c")),
              ("2",Array("d", "e", "f")),
              ("3",Array("g", "h", "k")))
```

Comment: Do you have a list of Arrays ? Like List(a,b,c)

Comment: Question seems a bit unclear. What is the output Array Type?, It is having `array[...]`. it seems to be a String. And it infers the output Array `Type`  as `Array[String]`

Comment: Thanks for your support. Actually, I have two fields in DB as Array[string], i want the combine them to reduce the query loading time with recursive . The output expect Array[{1, Array1[]},{2, Array2[]}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a list of input arrays

```
val a = Array("a", "b", "c")
val b = Array("d", "e", "f")
val c = Array("g", "h", "k")
List(a,b,c)
```

You can arrive at your desired solution by applying a simple function as follows

```
List(a,b,c).zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2.toString,x._1))
```

This will fetch you an output as

```
res0: List[(String, Array[String])] = List((0,Array(a, b, c)), (1,Array(d, e, f)), (2,Array(g, h, k)))
```

Comment: I accepted the answered with very clear to understand. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = Array("a", "b", "c")
b = Array("d", "e", "f")
c = Array("g", "h", "k")

def outArr(a:Array[String],b:Array[String],c:Array[String]) =
 Array(a,b,c).zipWithIndex.map{
  case (Array(a,b,c),x)=>"{\""+(x+1)+"\", array[\""+a+"\", \""+b+"\", \""+c+"\"]}" }
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> outArr(a,b,c)
res8: Array[String] = Array({"1", array["a", "b", "c"]}, {"2", array["d", "e", "f"]}, {"3", array["g", "h", "k"]})
```